# Get Microsoft Teams Shift per User - shiftrequests (deprecated) alternative

Tags: api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Good morning team,

We are trying to get all shift per-users on TEAMS SHIFT on API.

It seems we just can't get which API provides the information below.

[image]

When I do "Network" inspect online it seems the api calls this URL "https://api-nam1.staffhub.office.com/api/tenants/{tenant_id}/teams/{team_id}/shiftrequests" but this API standard is not documented on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Do you guys have an idea? (Been stuck on this for days)

Also,

The API that I tried was this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but the data is old (From March 03/2020) is there a way i can specify date ?

Comment: If any information or misunderstanding please let me know.

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts ?

Comment: Jaime, you need to use the one Stefan provided.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I used it before and it seems that it only returns 4 blue shifts. But our list has approximately 30 engineers.

Comment: @StefanWang Forgot to tag you on the response above. "Thanks, Stefan. I used it before and it seems that it only returns 4 blue shifts. But our list has approximately 30 engineers"

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT I updated the question. Let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Jaime Santos - `schedule-list-shifts` returns team's shared shifts. not per users.

Comment: @JaimeSantos - To fetch shifts perusers, `shiftrequests` should be used. (deprecated atm), You should use `timeoffreasons` instead. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-timeoffreasons

Answer (score 0):

- To get team members' shared shift, you should use `schedule-list-shifts`
- To get team members' all shifts, you should use `shiftrequests`

As `shiftrequests` is now deprecated, you have to use `timeoffreasons` instead.
You can find the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-timeoffreasons)